# Package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Tags: debian, packet

I have question similar to this one
[dpkg: new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48402/dpkg-new-pre-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-1)

I'm getting error same as above when trying to install PacketTracer 7.3.1. I think I declined EULA. I know nothing about bash and debconf. Does anyone know how to modify this script?

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -e


# Source debconf library.
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

remove_pt ()
{
if [ -e /opt/pt ]; then
  echo "Removing old version of Packet Tracer from /opt/pt"
  sudo rm -rf /opt/pt
  sudo rm -rf /usr/share/applications/cisco-pt7.desktop
  sudo rm -rf /usr/share/applications/cisco-ptsa7.desktop
  sudo rm -rf /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt7.png
fi
}




db_fset PacketTracer_731_amd64/show-eula seen false
db_fset PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula seen false
STATE=1 
while [ "$STATE" != 0 -a "$STATE" != 4 ]; do
    case "$STATE" in
    1)
        db_input critical PacketTracer_731_amd64/show-eula || true
    ;;
    2)
        db_input critical PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula || true
    ;;
    3)
        db_get PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula
        if [ "$RET" = "false" ]; then
            exit 1
        fi
    ;;
    esac

    if db_go; then
        STATE=$(($STATE + 1))
    else
        STATE=$(($STATE - 1))
    fi
done
```

This is what i got after adding set -x to preinst script and trying to install the packet.

````
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
+ [ !  ]
+ PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
+ export PERL_DL_NONLAZY
+ [  ]
+ exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst install 8.0.0 7.3.1
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
+ [ ! 1 ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exec
+ [  ]
+ exec
+ DEBCONF_REDIR=1
+ export DEBCONF_REDIR
+ db_fset PacketTracer_731_amd64/show-eula seen false
+ _db_cmd FSET PacketTracer_731_amd64/show-eula seen false
+ _db_internal_IFS=     

+ IFS= 
+ printf %%s\n FSET PacketTracer_731_amd64/show-eula seen false
+ IFS=  

+ IFS=
 read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=false
+ return 0
+ db_fset PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula seen false
+ _db_cmd FSET PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula seen false
+ _db_internal_IFS=     

+ IFS= 
+ printf %%s\n FSET PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula seen false
+ IFS=  

+ IFS=
 read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=false
+ return 0
+ STATE=1
+ [ 1 != 0 -a 1 != 4 ]
+ db_input critical PacketTracer_731_amd64/show-eula
+ _db_cmd INPUT critical PacketTracer_731_amd64/show-eula
+ _db_internal_IFS=     

+ IFS= 
+ printf %%s\n INPUT critical PacketTracer_731_amd64/show-eula
+ IFS=  

+ IFS=
 read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=question will be asked
+ return 0
+ db_go
+ _db_cmd GO 
+ _db_internal_IFS=     

+ IFS= 
+ printf %%s\n GO 
+ IFS=  

+ IFS=
 read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=ok
+ return 0
+ STATE=2
+ [ 2 != 0 -a 2 != 4 ]
+ db_input critical PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula
+ _db_cmd INPUT critical PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula
+ _db_internal_IFS=     

+ IFS= 
+ printf %%s\n INPUT critical PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula
+ IFS=  

+ IFS=
 read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=question will be asked
+ return 0
+ db_go
+ _db_cmd GO 
+ _db_internal_IFS=     

+ IFS= 
+ printf %%s\n GO 
+ IFS=  

+ IFS=
 read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=ok
+ return 0
+ STATE=3
+ [ 3 != 0 -a 3 != 4 ]
+ db_get PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula
+ _db_cmd GET PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula
+ _db_internal_IFS=     

+ IFS= 
+ printf %%s\n GET PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula
+ IFS=  

+ IFS=
 read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=false
+ return 0
+ [ false = false ]
+ exit 1
dpkg: error processing archive /home/yanaz/Pobrane/packet_tracer_modified.deb (--install):
 new packettracer package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.```
````

Comment: Did you intend to decline the EULA? If you’ve declined it, why do you still want to install the package?

Comment: I did it by an accident

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the EULA selection, you can change the value stored in the `debconf` database directly:

```
debconf-get-selections |
grep PacketTracer_731_amd64/accept-eula |
sed s/false/true/ |
sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Then configure pending packages:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --pending
```